# Is there any reason to replace JavaScript with JScript in Internet Expolorer?

Tags: javascript, performance, jscript

So when JScript is different from JavaScript, how does IE interpret jQuery, and all the other JavaScript-s ?

Is it better to replace the JavaScript with JScript for IE? Are there any performance diferences?

Comment: They both use the ECMA Script standard. http://www.ecmascript.org/

Comment: @zzzzBov Microsoft rarely follow the standarts and have different mind. Like about the box model... Only in the latest version they are starting to follow the specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JScript and JavaScript are the same. They're just aliases for each other:

(via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Comparison_to_JavaScript))

> As explained by JavaScript guru Douglas Crockford in his talk entitled *The JavaScript Programming Language* on YUI Theater, "[Microsoft] did not want to deal with Sun about the trademark issue, and so they called their implementation JScript. A lot of people think that JScript and JavaScript are different but similar languages. That's not the case. They are just different names for the same language, and the reason the names are different was to get around trademark issues."

The only scripting differences between the 2 will be in cross-browser differences.

Comment: So is there, any real use of JScript, any site that use JScipt instead of JavaScript?

Comment: JScript == JavaScript. The differences aren't in the name, but in the browser choice. (e.g., IE adds support for ActiveX controls.)

Answer (score 0):

As the other people said JavaScript and JScript are one and the same. IE interprets JQuery as any other JavaScript code. If fact JQuery implements workarounds for most browser inconsistencies, including those in IE.

About the performance - IE JScript/JavaScript performance is awful compared to all other modern browsers. Awful as in more then 10 times worse.

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do to speed it up, besides trying to persuade your visitors to use another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an extra script for IE browsers only-

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="jsforie.js"></script>
```

It will boost the performance of the other browsers.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is this boosting IE or other browsers? Where did you find it? What is it?